# Distribute $4$ people into $3$ rooms when each can contain any number of people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I want to check my answer about: distributing $4$ people into $3$-distinct rooms, and each room can contain any number of people.

First consider the rooms indistinguishable, and list the size in decreasing order for each possible rooms summary(e.g. 4,0,0 means there is one room assigned 4 people, the others empty), and count the combination for each:

$$\begin{align}
4,0,0&: C(4,4) &=1\\
3,1,0&: C(4,3)C(1,1) &=4\\
2,2,0&: C(4,2)C(2,2)/2! &=3\\
2,1,1&: C(4,2)C(2,1)C(1,1)/2!. &=6\\
\end{align}$$

Then compute the permutation each:

$$\begin{align}
4,0,0&: C(4,4)\cdot 3!/2! &=1\cdot 3\\
3,1,0&: C(4,3)C(1,1)\cdot 3! &=4\cdot 6\\
2,2,0&: C(4,2)C(2,2)/2!\cdot 3!/2! &=3\cdot 3\\
2,1,1&: C(4,2)C(2,1)C(1,1)/2!\cdot 3!/2!. &=6\cdot 3\\
\end{align}$$

Is the answer 3+24+9+18=54 correct?

Comment: Finally I realized that the *rooms summary* I was saying is distributing indistinguishable objects into indistinguishable groups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the rooms and the people are distinguishable, then each person has 3 rooms to choose from, so the answer is $3^4=81$.

Your mistake is the $/2!$ in the last two lines of the first calculation. Or, specifically, that when you suddenly make a distinction between the rooms, you don't take them away. For instance, you don't make a distinction between
$$
ab, c,d
$$
and
$$
ab,d,c
$$
in the final calculation (where $a,b,c,d$ are the people and $a$ and $b$ share room).

Similarly, you don't make a distinction between
$$
ab,cd,
$$
and
$$
cd,ab,
$$
This change makes the sum into $3+24+18+36=81$.

Comment: Your answer assumes ordered individuals and distinct room.  The problem has neither - rooms are indistinct and the order of the people within a room is irrelevant.

Comment: @CoditoErgoCogitoSum Nope. The calculations done in the OP implies that the persons are distinguishable (the second line in the first calculation is how to pick three people to be in one room together, and one person to be alone, when the rooms are indistinguishable). Also, the rooms are indistinguishable in the first calculation, then making them distinguishable is the point of the second calculation.

Comment: Individuals are not distinguishable within a room though.  They are distinguished when spread over multiple rooms. The order two or three or four people are selected for a single room is not relevant in the end.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum We haven't ordered the people who share room. What have you that idea?

Comment: Now I completely understand the error you pointed out, so thank you! But in your description, I think my problem is opposite to "*you don't take them away*". Instead I took to much away so my answer was smaller...

Comment: My way of taking two '/2!' away is different from you, but both work I think... Anyway I share with you: '/2!' can be taken way from '3!/2!' in *the last calculation*, since if I list 123, 132, ... below any given instance $ab, c, d$, 123 and 132 are different(c2,d3 v.s. c3,d2), so '/2!' is not needed. From first calculation also works: Given any $ab,c,d$ and again list 123, 132,... below it and count $3!$, then I will count something twice, since I can swap $c,d$ in $ab,c,d$, then the 123-list is now for $ab,d,c$. e.g.123 for $ab,c,d$ is the same as 132 for $ab,d,c$.so $/2!$ is need.